# Складываем время. Присвоение значения TimeSpan

Tags: c#

Есть список временных промежутков с указанием начального и конечного времени

```
countTimeList = new List<(DateTime, DateTime)>();
```

нам нужно их всех сложить.

```
TimeSpan? job;
foreach (var time in countTimeList)
{
    TimeSpan t = time.Item2 - time.Item1;
    job += t;
}
```

Но нужно вначале как то присвоить job нулевое значение, что бы его можно было складывать. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто используйте не `TimeSpan?`, а обычную структуру, у неё значение по уполчанию равно 0 (00:00:00). Например:

```
var job = new TimeSpan();
foreach (var time in countTimeList)
    job += time.Item2 - time.Item1;
```

Ну или если вам все же нужен `Nullable` тип, то и `TimeSpan? job = new TimeSpan();` работать будет.